# odoo 14 point of sale receipt customization

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb, pos

I'm trying to customize pos receipt in odoo 14 ce but it not work
help me please
this is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="OrderReceipt" t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='pos-receipt-contact']" position="inside">
            <div>Customer name: <span t-esc="receipt.client"/></div>
        </xpath>

    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: `receipt.client` is an object. Try to use `receipt.client.name`

Comment: thanks it's working